# Group By SPListItem in SharePoint SPListItemCollection

Tags: groups, splistitem, grouping, splistitemcollection

I have custom list. with calculated column **Department Group**.

Department group column takes first left letter of title columns in uppercase.

[image]

using **SPListItemCollection** I'm able to get all items. 
but now I am trying to bind the group record in different table.

**example:**

```
         all record of Department group : A in one table
         all record of Department group : B in one table
```

so I think for that I need grouping for in **SPListItemCollection**

I am stuck here help me.

my sample code

```
   using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);

                if (list != null) { 
                SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = " <Where>"+
                              "<IsNotNull>"+
                              "<FieldRef Name='DepartmentGroup' />"+
                              "</IsNotNull>"+
                              "</Where>"+
                              "<OrderBy>"+
                              "<FieldRef Name='DepartmentGroup' Ascending='True' />"+
                              "</OrderBy>";

                SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

Comment: I think `GroupBy` won't be helpful if you are looking for making it to different tables.

Comment: How many Departments you can have? Is it fix or not sure??

Comment: I have department from A To Z

Comment: so suggest better options for group by..

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a reference to `System.Linq` , filter your `SPListItemCollection` using a `Where` `Linq` clause and bind the result to a table as desired.

Example:

```
var deptA = items.Cast<SPListItem>().Where(p => p.DepartmentGroup== "A")
```